# Pgfplots: Bar chart in a "old school" style (halftone filling)

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

I would like to know how it is possible to get a texture similar to the image that shows bars in a more "old school" style.

[image]

I can only apply a very common style

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title=Title,
    xbar,
    xmajorgrids = true,
    bar width=6mm, 
    width=12cm, height=5.5cm, 
    enlarge y limits=0.2,
    xlabel={\#number},
    symbolic y coords={A,B,C,D},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]

    \addplot coordinates {(1,A) (7,B) (5,C)(2,D)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the **fill of the bars**? To me, it looks like an **artifact from scanning** a printed diagram :).

Comment: Yes. But is it possible to approximate this characteristic?

Comment: The word you should be searching for is halftone. Sometimes this can be done by a printer driver.  It can be done by GIMP using filters->distorts->newsprint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) that defines a new `stipple` verb to be used with a path, instead of `fill`.

[image: Stippled bars]

I've not tried to make it very robust (like checking the argument actually is a closed path, etc), and you might like to experiment with the size and/or shape of the pen used to draw the dots, and the spacing, and the amount of random grey used, but it might be a starting point.  For a large area you will get a great many dots, which will make the output larger and slower to process.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

def stipple primary pp = 
    interim bboxmargin := 0;
    for x = xpart llcorner bbox pp step 1/4 until xpart urcorner bbox pp:
        for y = ypart llcorner bbox pp step 1/4 until ypart urcorner bbox pp:
            drawdot (x,y) withpen pencircle scaled 1/2 withcolor (1/4 + uniformdeviate 1/2);
        endfor
    endfor
enddef;

beginfig(1);

    path a, b, c; 

    a = unitsquare xscaled 21 yscaled 34;
    b = unitsquare xscaled 21 yscaled 55 shifted 34 right;
    c = unitsquare xscaled 21 yscaled 89 shifted 68 right;

    forsuffixes $=a,b,c:
        stipple $; draw $;
    endfor

endfig;
end.
```

Note: to get a shade of grey in MP the syntax is `withcolor n` where `n` is a numeric variable.  Values of `n` less than or equal to 0 are treated as black; values greater than or equal to 1 are treated as white; values in between are treated as shades of grey.

The code as posted above works fine with rectangular paths where the `bbox` is the same shape as the path, but will not work well with any other type of shape, such as a circle.  You can fix this by stippling the `bbox` then clipping to the path.  Here's an improved routine:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

vardef stipple primary pp = 
    save ff; picture ff; ff=image(
    for x = xpart llcorner bbox pp step 1/4 until xpart urcorner bbox pp:
        for y = ypart llcorner bbox pp step 1/4 until ypart urcorner bbox pp:
            drawdot (x,y) withpen pencircle scaled 1/2 withcolor (1/4 + uniformdeviate 1/2);
        endfor
    endfor
    ); clip ff to pp; draw ff;
enddef;

beginfig(1);

    path a, b, c, d; 

    a = unitsquare xscaled 21 yscaled 34;
    b = unitsquare xscaled 21 yscaled 55 shifted 34 right;
    c = unitsquare xscaled 21 yscaled 89 shifted 68 right;

    d = fullcircle scaled  21 shifted 20 left;

    forsuffixes $=a,b,c,d:
        stipple $; draw $;
    endfor

endfig;
end.
```

that should fill arbitrary closed paths properly.

[image]